# Why are My Accordion Elements Not Expanding the Webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have built a simple webpage for my school homepage. I'm using accordions to contain the links, but the accordion units are not extending the webpage. In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPXg9/11/), the 'Student Links' accordion extends the `<body>` length - but the other accordion containers won't. I recently received help regarding the placement of the accordions, allowing me to have two on the same line. Upon doing this, the two on the same line don't extend the webpage.

```
<title>PHHS Main Page</title>

<body style="background-color: #D9F3FD">
<div id="bodyWrapper">
<p class="style1"><span class="style4" id="PHHS">PHHS</span> Home Screen</p>
    <div class="accordionWrapper">
        <div id="accordionStudents">
            <h1>Student Links</h1>
                <div>
                    <table border-color="white" id="table1">
                        <tr id="table1Row1">
                            <td class="table1Row1Data1">Bell Schedule</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">TeacherEase</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">Powerschool</td>
                            <td class="tableRow1Data1">Library Information</td>
                        <tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Link</td>
                            <td>Link</td>
                            <td>Link</td>
                            <td>Link</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordionWrapper accordion-inline">
        <div id="accordionTeachers" class="accordion-custom">
            <h1>Teacher Links</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Test Teacher Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionLibrary" class="accordion-custom">
            <h1>PHHS Library Information</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Text Library Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: They have to be on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <div class="accordionWrapper accordion-inline">
        <div id="accordionTeachers" class="accordion-custom">
            <h1>Teacher Links</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Test Teacher Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionLibrary" class="accordion-custom">
            <h1>PHHS Library Information</h1>
            <div>
                <p>Text Library Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then

```
.accordion-inline .accordion-custom {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

you need to remove `float: left` from `#accordionTeachers` and `#accordionLibrary`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vPNyg/)

Comment: This works fine, but I'm still unable to extend the main light-blue element when the accordion is opened. When I first created this project, and introduced the unedited accordion units, the height of the light-blue background would extend accordion to the height difference of the opened to unopened accordion box. The effect can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/L46Nh/

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't so jumbled with like 8234 different accordion things (and I am deathly afraid of `<table>`s) I would totally churn away and fix this all up for you.

```
#accordionTeachers {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
#accordionLibrary {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6%;
}
```

The issue you are running into resides here.  Using a `float: left;` is a nifty trick most of the time, but your accordions have to be on the ground to push the other elements around like they should.

Remove the `float: left;` from those two and you're well on your way to victory.  Unfortunately it seems you have already formatted AROUND the idea of the floats so that may take a little work to undo.

If you really want them to be in the same row you can use `display: inline-block;` but when one opens, the other will be pushed down with the bottom.